# CakePHP login with URL

Tags: url, cakephp, authentication

i want to provide the possibility to login on my website by passing the username and password in the url. Something like this:

http://vabdat.local/rest/bpid/34.xml?User=Mustermann&password=abcdef123

But i have no idea how to solve that problem. I `m actually using CakePHP 2.x

```html
public function beforeFilter() {  
  
  if(in_array(strtolower($this->params['controller']),array('rest'))){
    
  
   $user = $this->Auth->identify($this->request, $this->response);
      $this->Auth->login($user);
      $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic' => array (
         'fields' => array('User.username' => 'Username', 'User.password' => 'Password'),
         'userModel' => 'User',
         'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
       'scope' => array (
      'User.active' => 1,
        )
      ) );
      $this->Security->unlockedActions = array();
      
      
   }
     
    else{  
    
              
       }
      
 }
```

Can someone tell me how to find a solution to this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems like an absolutely terrible idea.  Are you sure you want or need to go this route?

Comment: Never ever do that, there are at least 3 major security issues here. Use better one-time-tokens to login. In the past I have used [Qurls/Qlogins](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/08/qlogin-quicklogins-fur-cakephp/) which at least don't expose plain text passwords etc.